# Как с помощью jquery вывести данные полученные от php обработчика

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, json

Сильно не ругайте, только осваиваю.
Вообщем этот код отправляет данные из формы (vorota=3,zabor=125...)обработчику на php если хоть одно значение формы изменено.
Все отправляется, но мне нужно получить ответ и поместить данные в уже имеющиеся на странице поля <td id="vorota">, <td id="zabor">, <td id="...">, 
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

```
$(function(){
var ajax_timeout=false, delay_beforesend=3000;
function sendForm(){
   $.ajax({
     url:'calc-function.php',
     data:$('form').serialize(),
     method:'post'
   })
}

$('form').find('select, input').change(function(){
     if(ajax_timeout) clearTimeout(ajax_timeout);
     ajax_timeout=setTimeout(sendForm,delay_beforesend)
})
})
```

Comment: ок, response.
Но как эти ответы подставить в поля страницы?
<td id="vorota">
<td id="zabor">

Comment: апдейтил код

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понял.
Данные отправлены несколько переменных), обработаны, далее php должен отправить результаты вычеслений. Каким образом отправить несколько переменных?
И как дальше их принять? Просто расписать:
success: function(response){
      $("#vorota").html(response)
$("#vorota").html(response)
$("#vorota").html(response)

Comment: В php обработчике ты должен выводить эти переменные. Можно в JSON и тогда указать у ajax dataType: "JSON". Но я думаю Вы ничего не понимаете и вам рано практиковаться с ajax. Читайте статьи как оно работает и станет всё ясно.

Comment: Спасибо! Данные приходят, осталось только разобраться как их вывести...

Comment: Я же написал как их вывести $("#vorota").html(response.vorota)

Comment: Есть на странице <td id="amount"></td> но ничего там не появляется, хотя Firebug показывает что ответ со значением есть, "amount":1234

Comment: что выведет код alert(response) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP обработчик:

```
/* Bla-Bla-Bla */
echo json_encode(array('vorota'=>$vorota,'amount'=>$amount, 'razmer'=>$razmer));
```

Клиент:

```
function sendForm(){
   $.ajax({
     url:'calc-function.php',
     data:$('form').serialize(),
     dataType: "JSON",
     method:'post',
     success: function(response){
      $("#vorota").html(response.vorota);
      $("#amount").html(response.amount);
      $("#razmer").html(response.razmer);
     }
   })
}
```

response и есть ответ сервера.

Comment: Все! Разобрался! Просто код был в head, перенес в тело и все заработало! Спасибо большое!!! :)

Comment: Всё замечательно, с чекбоксами, с селектами, но вот если после ввода в инпут не нажать на энтер или не перейти на другой инпут, то данные с него не отправляются :(
www.chelzabor.ru/utilite/calc/